# Schwarzchild Metric ODE for θ solution

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, geodesics

Consider the schwarzchild metric and one of its geodesic differential equation $$r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\phi'^2-r^2 \theta''=0$$ where $f'\equiv \frac{d}{d \tau}:\forall f \in \mathbb{R}$. How would I go about solving this ODE  for $\theta''$since it includes both $\phi'$ and $\theta''$? Will one part of the equation always go to zero? Thats the case for the geodesic on a sphere. Note that is 1 equation for a set of 4 ODE's

Comment: For one, it seems to simplify to: $\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\phi'^2-\theta''=0$

Comment: yes, but how would I start to solve will the $\phi'$go to zero?

Comment: I see. There's not enough information to solve this. You need a second ODE, at least. But I think my simplification holds, I think, for $r\neq 0$

Comment: They are four _simultaneous_ equations, and can be solved using RK4.  You need to turn them into eight first-order equations first though.  This is a standard procedure for second order ODEs.